# What would be a good way to create a model for bunch of check boxes in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a model for these check boxes below. There is also dosage text input next to each check box. I think there should be a better way to save it to database rather than creating field for each check box and dosage text field in the model.

[image: Check Boxes]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Medication` model that saves the type of drug you want to store and then use ManyToMany relationships with through (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships )

For example:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    medication_dosages = models.ManyToManyField(Medication, through='MedicationDosage')

class Medication(models.model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MedicationDosage(models.Model)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    medication = models.ForeignKey(Medication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dosage = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```